# Typecasting in division in C

Tags: c, casting

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int t;
    long long int a[100000], n, i;
    scanf("%d\n", &t);
    while(t){
        t--;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%ld\n", n);
        n = n * (n-1);
        printf("%ld\n", n);
        n = n/2;
        printf("%ld\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out the problem in division. It's returning garbage value in the third printf statement. Can you please help me identify where the problem is?

Comment: Better to ensure the heap  for large array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format specifier for `long long int` is `lld`, not `ld`.

That's *especially* important in the `scanf` as using the wrong specifier may end up putting the data in the wrong bytes within the variable.

Comment: Thanks!! That was the problem using lld for scanf as well as printf statement.